# Comparing, combining and determining the length of the strings?

Tags: c, string

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this program.
Write a function that takes in two strings. The function should combine the two strings with the string that comes first lexicographically. There should be a space between the two strings. Print the resultant string on one line. Print the length of the resultant string on one line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){

char word1[10];
char word2[10];
int length;

//getting the words from input given by the user
printf("Enter the first word. (10 Letters or less)\n");
scanf("%s", word1);
printf("Enter the second word. (10 Letters or less)\n");
scanf("%s", word2);

//comparing the two words entered
if (strcmp(word1, word2)>0)
    printf("%s comes before %s\n", word2, word1);
else if (strcmp(word1, word2)<0)
    printf("%s comes before %s\n", word1, word2);
else
    printf("Both words are the same!\n");

//combining the two words
strcat(word1, " ");
strcat(word1, word2);
printf("\n%s\n", word1);

//looking at the length of the two words
length = strlen(word1) + strlen(word2) - 1;
printf("The length of the words are %d.\n", length);

return 0;
}
```

That is my code above. I decided to print out which word would come first for my own visualization. I'm not sure though how combine the words so that the one that is lexicographically first would be first and how to determine the length of resulted combination of the two. I thought that by adding minus 1 would take out the effect of the space when combining the words but the string length is always off by different numbers when I put different words into the program. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: there is not enough length to `word1`. Also, no add `strlen(word2)`, word1 include word2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version that leaves memory allocation with the caller:

```
/** Return 0 if not enough space, else length of resultant string. */
int stringOrder(const char * const str1, const char * const str2, char* retBuf, int bufLen)
{
    const char* first = str1;
    const char* second = str2;
    int requiredLength = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 2;

    if (requiredLength > bufLen)
        return 0;

    if(strcmp(str1, str2) == 1)
    {
        first = str2;
        second = str1;
    }

    strcpy(retBuf, first);
    strcat(retBuf, " ");
    strcat(retBuf, second);

    return requiredLength - 1;
}
```

Usage like this:

```
    #define LENGTH 128
    const char* str1 = "world";
    const char* str2 = "hello";

    char result[128] = "";

    int ok = stringOrder(str1, str2, result, LENGTH);

    if (ok)
        printf("%s\n", result);
    else
        printf("Not enough space");
```